# navigate with arrow keys in thumbnail gallery

Tags: javascript, html

I made this image gallery a while ago and now had the idea, that it would be great if you could navigate in it with the arrow keys (left and right).
As I'm relatively new to programming, I cannot get it working with what I found in the forum.
I would be very happy if anyone could help :)

At the bottom there's a link to the gallery on jsfiddle.

And here is what the gallery looks like:

The javascript in the head of the document:

```
    function reset()
            {
            var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
            }

        function init()

                {document.getElementById('img1');}

                window.onload = init;
```

the CSS:

```
                #large  {
                        width:820px; 
                        height:619px; 
                        background:url(image_I_820x619.jpg) 
                        no-repeat center;}



          .thumb66x50   {
                        width:66px; 
                        height:50px;}
```

And the body of the image gallery:

```
<div id="large"></div>          

<img id="img1" src="thumbnail_image_I.jpg" class='thumb66x50' alt="" onclick="reset();document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(image_I_820x619.jpg)';">

<img id="img2" src="thumbnail_image_II.jpg" class='thumb66x50' alt="" onclick="reset();document.getElementById('large').style.backgroundImage='url(image_II_820x619.jpg)';">
```

Here's the the gallery on jsfiddle:
(Strangely, it only works there, if I put the javascript in the html panel...)

[https://jsfiddle.net/cv6k9k0f/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/cv6k9k0f/5/)

Comment: Your gallery does nothing.   What's `imgs[i];` ? where's the HTML? where's the CSS... PLEASE create a [mcve] of what you have and describe the best you can what's wrong and what's the desired gallery behavior.

Comment: [edit] your question, use the `<>` button in the editor to create a Code Snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your posts! The code displays correctly now and I got the gallery working on jsfiddle :) I put the link in the original post.
Also I removed the {imgs[i];} which was a rest of some mouseover-effects.

Comment: What's `reset();` for? What's the JS part doing actually? makes no sense to me. It's a complete mess

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your solution is to keep the JS logic in one place. The following will work for any number of thumbnails.

```js
(function () {

  let lg = document.querySelector("#large"),
      sm = document.querySelectorAll("[data-bg]"),
      setBg = (el = sm[0]) => lg.style.backgroundImage = `url('${ el.dataset.bg }')`;

  Array.from(sm).forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", setBg.bind(this, el)));
  setBg();
  
}());
```

```css
#large{
  height: 130px;
  background: #000 none 50% 50% / cover;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

[data-bg] {
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="large" role="presentation"></div>          

<img src="//placehold.it/60x50/bf0" data-bg="//placehold.it/800x600/bf0" alt="Green">
<img src="//placehold.it/60x50/0bf" data-bg="//placehold.it/800x600/0bf" alt="Azure">
<img src="//placehold.it/60x50/f0b" data-bg="//placehold.it/800x600/f0b" alt="Fuxxy">
```